# Want to create a log file of chef-client execution

Tags: logging, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to create a log file of the chef-client execution at `/root/logs` path.
How to add code in recipe file that will create a logs file in above location?
Please help me with this.

Comment: What is wrong with the logs in `/var/log/chef` ?

Answer (score 8):

Run the chef client with -L option followed by expected log location.

`chef-client -L /root/logs/chef-client.log`

https://docs.chef.io/debug.html#chef-client

Comment: @sumitsalunke - If this helped, please accept this as answer [http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]